# CSS margin edits mess up mobile site

Tags: css, shopify, css-position, margin, positioning

I've been trying to move specific contents of our product page down on Shopify. I moved a button on the page to the top left. The code inserted in our theme.scss for the new positioning of the button was:

```
.btn--secondary{
position:absolute;
left:228px;
top:40px;
font-size: 8px;
padding: 10px 32px;
margin-bottom: 350px;
```

}

I also changed the margins on the product image and title:

```
    .product-single__media {
      margin-top: 50px;
      min-height: 1px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative; }
        .product-single__media iframe,
        .product-single__media model-viewer,
        .product-single__media .shopify-model-viewer-ui,
        .product-single__media img,
        .product-single__media > video,
        .product-single__media .plyr,
        .product-single__media .media-item {



      .product-single__title {
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
        margin-top: 50px;}
```

These changes made the mobile version of the site totally get cut off halfway through. Is there any way that this can be fixed so that the mobile version appears the same as the desktop version?

Comment: Could you provide more html code, or show us a screen shot of your desired output. Additionally .product-single__media .media-item { these selectors are missing a closing  curly braces and content.

Comment: hey there Mohammad. I acctually was just able to figure out the issue! I had additional code at the bottom of my theme.scss file that was overriding this change and cutting off mobile view. But the code above ended up working on desktop and mobile for repositioning of the content! Thanks for reaching out!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, just a side note consider using !important wherever you think something is overridden somewhere, after you figure out that something is overwritten you can give a higher specificity to that element

Comment: awesome. thank you so much for that suggestion!!!